# Does Instagram have something like Twitter's Intent or Facebook's Sharer functionality?

Tags: instagram, hashtag

We have a web page that currently has two links to allow users the ability to pre-populate a Twitter tweet and a Facebook post with some text, with the key point being the hashtags (and mention for Twitter).

They're now asking about adding something similar for Instagram, but my search terms with the inclusion of 'intent' are pulling up either how to do this on Twitter, or via Android.

If it helps, this is the Twitter and Facebook versions we're trying to replicate, but for Instagram.

```
<div id="shareLinks">
    <a href="<%= string.Format("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={0}",
        Server.UrlEncode("___ (@___) ___! #___")) %>"
        onclick="window.open(this.href, '', 'width=550, height=420');return false;"
        target="_blank" class="button tiny secondary">Tweet the good news!</a>
    <a href="<%= string.Format("http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={0}&amp;t={1}",
        Server.UrlEncode("http://example.com"), Server.UrlEncode("___ #___")) %>"
        onclick="window.open(this.href, '', 'width=626, height=436');return false;"
        target="_blank" class="button tiny secondary">Post the good news!</a>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing

> Instagram has a vibrant creative community, and third party apps that allow users to create images and share them through the Instagram native apps can offer people additional opportunities for creative expression. However, we’ve gotten feedback that the pre-filled captions coming through this sharing channel often feel spammy. In an effort to protect our community and keep interactions on Instagram authentic, we are removing pre-filled captions from mobile sharing.
>
> Beginning today, the iOS Hooks and Android Intents will stop accepting captions passed by third party apps. This is a non-breaking change: existing mobile apps that utilize pre-filled captions will continue to be able to use this flow to share media through the Instagram apps, but now Instagram will ignore the caption text. To create a caption for a photo or video shared by a third party app, users will have to enter a caption manually, the same way they already do when sharing content using the Instagram native apps.
>
> We hope this change will continue to foster high-quality, authentic sharing on Instagram.

Comment: So much like Facebook has done. However, it appears this is applicable to iOS and Android applications, and not web sites. Given the above, I'm guessing we can't include a pre-filled message, but can we at least add a link to open the Instagram site or application?

Comment: @JamesSkemp Hmmm on what grounds are you saying this doesn't apply to web sites? From what I understood websites are 'apps', much like Android and iOS apps.

Comment: Context, and that I haven't found any examples that can be used to trigger sharing via a link on a web page. Instead, my search found how to trigger this in native apps. If you can update your answer with the HTML for an example link that I can put into a web page, like the Facebook/Twitter functionality, then that would be awesome!